# Could not find group info of kafka when using spark streaming

Tags: python, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have the following simple spark streaming progress which consuming message from a kafka topic `test` with group id `feature1` and just printing the result. However, when I run `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server zookeeper-1:9092 --list` to list all groups, there is no `feature1` or anything containing `feature1`. What's the problem?

My spark version is `2.1.2`, kafka version is `2.12-2.0.0`, zookeeper version is `3.4.13`. And I found some issue related to it here https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager/issues/207, but I don't know weather the problem in my case is related to the issue.

```
# coding=utf8

import sys
import datetime
import time

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark_conf = SparkConf()
    spark_conf.set('spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition', 1)
    sc = SparkContext("local[2]", "NetworkWordCount", conf=spark_conf)
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)

    # Create a DStream that will connect to hostname:port, like localhost:9999
    kafka_params = {
        "bootstrap.servers":"zookeeper-1:9092",
        "group.id":"feature1",
        "auto.offset.reset":"smallest",
        "session.timeout.ms":"60000",
        "request.timeout.ms":"100000",
    }
    lines = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ["test"], kafka_params)
    # lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, 'zookeeper-1:2181', 'feature1', {'new-one':1})
    lines.pprint()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

The output of group list is as following and sudo doesn't change anything.

```
console-consumer-9215
console-consumer-41888
console-consumer-32417
console-consumer-35073
console-consumer-66656
```

And there is a strange phenomenon, `feature1` appears in `/consumers` directory of zookeeper, while console-consumer-* groups does not.

Comment: Just tried this command and it worked for me, can you post what response you get? are you seeing other group-ids connected on this kafka server? (maybe add sudo)

Comment: I have posted the response I get. The console-consumer-* group id is created by `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning`. which works normally. @AbhiskekN

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet is what the kafka script runs at the backend to fetch the consumer groups. Try this out to print the consumer groups and see if your group is being printed (take care of the "filter"), it's in Scala.

Kafka Version: 1.0.0
, Scala Version: 2.12.0

```
import kafka.admin.AdminClient

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers","<kafka-bootstrap>:9092")

    AdminClient.create(props).listAllConsumerGroupsFlattened().map(_.groupId).filter(_.contains("mx-")).mkString(";").split(";").foreach(println(_))

  }
```

Comment: How could I run it? I'm not familier with scala. I've installed sbt. Could you describe in detail?